# Why does Cellular Data usage summary include WiFi data?

Tags: wifi, cellular-data, iphone

Under Settings -> Cellular Data there is a nice break out of how much data each app has used.  I expected this to allow me to identify which specific apps were using the most cellular data so I avoid overage fees.  My carrier tells me how much data I have used, but only gives a general category of where my data is going, which is useless for this purpose.

However, I have only had the phone a couple of weeks, and it is claiming I have already used 17.4GB of data.  However, per my carrier, I have actually used only 150MB.  It is obviously counting WiFi in the cellular figures.  But why?  Am I looking at the wrong spot?  Is there a bug in iOS?  Something I am doing wrong?  Something I need to enable? Could it be counting previous months on a different phone and need a reset somehow? Shouldn't it reset every month?

Comment: Turns out despite only having the phone for a week, it somehow was counting data usage from the previous phone since 2013...

Comment: I don't see how this is a dupe.  I am voting to leave open and not close it.

Comment: @Allan The question was based on the mistaken assumption that WiFi data was being included in the usage summary, when in fact what was happening was the "current period" was counting actual cellular usage from a previous phone.

Comment: the suspected dupe link refers to the last time the phone was reset.  This refers to a new phone.  That's significantly different

Comment: @Allan Something during the setup transferred the reset period from the old phone to the new phone, making it appear like it was older.  The new phone was activated in January 2016 but the statistics said the usage was counted from mid-2013.  Resetting the statistics per the answer to the linked question fixed the problem.